# storeSetACL Amazon S3 grant full control to owner by ID, not e-mail address

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-s3, coldfusion-10

I'm so close to getting this working.  Apparently, my e-mail address is associated with an account other than my AWS account, so when I try to set ACL for owner by e-mail I get an error from Amazon "AmbiguousGrantByEmailAddress".  As best as I could find in their forums and docs was that you could set it by the 12 digit ID of the account.  However - I can't find the documents that show me the correct name of the key to set.

```
all_read = {group="all", permission="read"};
authenticated_read = {group="authenticated", permission="read"};
owner_full = {id="nnnn-nnnn-nnnn", permission="full_control"};
aclObj = [owner_full, all_read, authenticated_read];
```

I've tried both id="nnnn-nnnn-nnnn" and id="nnnnnnnnnnnn" and I keep getting InvalidKey.

Answer (score 3):

SOLUTION (for others that come across this).

The key is "ID", but it's not the 12-digit user ID of the account [despite an Amazon developer stating that on their forums page], it's the **canonical ID** of the account.  Both can be found on the AWS Security Credentials page.